# Where does rails log errors in javascript?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails so sorry if the answer is obvious, I couldn't find anything via search. Right now I have my view rendering _box.js.erb which simply draws a box. Inside _box.js.erb, which works correctly under normal circumstances, I introduce a simple syntax error like an unmatched parenthesis. When I load the webpage, my box doesn't show up. I look in logs/development.logs and it has no mention of my javascript syntax error. Is this error being caught somewhere? If so, how can I display it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error occurs on the client, not the server, so ROR cannot log it.

If you're using Firefox, install Firebug. Other browsers have JavaScript consoles, usually opened by pressing F-12 or looking on the "developer" options on the application menus.

Comment: Oh that makes sense, I forgot that JS is client side.

Comment: ⌘+⌥+J on Mac (Chrome and Safari)

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a controller to accept javascript errors, so when there's a client side error you can just send it to a javascript error collection endpoint which in turn could take the contents of the error and add it to the Rails log or whatever log.

[This old gem](https://github.com/girishso/rails-client-logger) does that. I realize this questions is 8 years old.